# Setting up a miner

Tags: mining-hardware

Before I decide to buy a miner, I wanted to know what I would need to get it up and running, such as cords, equipment, etc. I've got my eye on a $35.00 1.4 Th/s ASIC miner, and i'm hoping anything else i need will be less than $15. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $35 dollars sounds pretty cheap. Are you sure that offer is for an intact device?

Answer (score 1):

$35 is a good deal, may be *too* good.

Well there are a couple of things I would recommend.

1. Somewhere to put your miner. Maybe an open-air rack? You really don't want it to be mining in the corner of your house.
2. Extra cooler? Maybe some external heat-sinks and a good fan you can aim at the miner
3. Your miner should come with power cables, etc. I wouldn't expect to need any. But if you're worried, ask the seller if the miner comes with cables.
4. If you really want, a solar panel if you don't have one already. Doesn't have to be solely for your miner, you could use it as a long-term investment :)

Comment: Now that I'm looking at the product, it says it is a 1.4T ASIC miner. Is "1.4T" just the name, or is it the hashpower?

Comment: Not really sure. You'll have to mine to test out. Usually is should be rated at "1.4 TH/s, not 1.4T. If it doesn't say the speed anywhere else however, this will probably be the speed.

Comment: I'm not sure, because in the title, it says not only 1.4T, but later in the title it says 300G. It's really confusing.